# Cannot position clear button properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a clear buttons that need to be positioned inside input boxes.

**The main issue is that the orientation of the form keeps changing based on screen size.**

[image]

[image]

**[Link to DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/danielnewtown/3c35qv0w/)**

---

**[Link to DEMO2 (vanburenx's answer)](http://jsfiddle.net/danielnewtown/3c35qv0w/2/)**

I read following questions but in all of them the form is either horizontal or vertical. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695091/position-clear-button-in-bootstrap-input-field) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111336/form-clear-button-function-doesnt-work-properly) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577602/clear-button-empties-textarea-but-i-cannot-repopulate-it) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280378/chrome-not-positioning-button-properly)

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.2.1/bootstrap-social.css">
<style>
.top-container {
    width: 76%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 45px;
}
.links a, .login button, .login input{
    display: inline-block
}
.login-form-input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .login input {
        width: 100%
    }
}
@media ( min-width :601px) and ( max-width :767px) {
    .login input {
    width: 44%
}
}
@media ( min-width :768px) and ( max-width :900px) {
    .login input {
    width: 49%;
}
}
@media ( min-width :1200px){
    .login input {
    width: 45%;
}
}
.searchclear {
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:14px;
    margin:auto;
    font-size:14px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
            <div class="top">
                <div class="top-container">
                    <div class="login">
                        <form id="myForm" role="form" action="#" method="GET">

                            <input  id="input1" name="input1"
                                class="form-control login-form-input searchinput" type="text" value="">
                                <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="display:block"></span>

                            <input id="input2" name="input2" class="form-control login-form-input searchinput"
                                type="text" value="">
                                <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="display:block"></span>

                            <button class="submit-button" type="submit" title="Submit">
                                <div>Submit
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </form>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
</header>
<script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchinput").keyup(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle(Boolean($(this).val()));
    });
    $(".searchclear").toggle(Boolean($(".searchinput").val()));
    $(".searchclear").click(function () {
        $(this).prev().val('').focus();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you know, its easier for us to help if you show us what you want it to look like, and create a jsfiddle of what you have now, and we can help you much faster that way. Pasting your entire code makes this way harder than it needs to be

Comment: @AbdulAhmad thanks for your suggestion I do not have a JSFiddle will update the question upon creating one.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad demo is included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstraps built in `has-feedback` class to place the icon inside the input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hasclear").keyup(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.next('span').toggle(Boolean(t.val()));
  });

  $(".clearer").hide($(this).prev('input').val());

  $(".clearer").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.login .glyphicon-remove-circle {
  padding-top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.top-container {
  width: 76%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 45px;
}
.links a,
.login button,
.login input {
  display: inline-block
}
.login .form-group .login-form-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .login input,
  .login .form-group {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .login input,
  .login .form-group {
    width: 44%;
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .login input,
  .login .form-group {
    width: 49%;
    display: block !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .login input,
  .login .form-group {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="top-container">
      <div class="login">
        <form id="myForm" role="form" action="#" method="GET" class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input id="txt1" type="text" class="login-form-input form-control hasclear" placeholder="Textbox 1" /> <span class="clearer glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle form-control-feedback"></span>

          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input id="txt1" type="text" class="login-form-input form-control hasclear" placeholder="Textbox 1" /> <span class="clearer glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle form-control-feedback"></span>

          </div>
          <button class="submit-button" type="submit" title="Submit">
            <div>Submit</div>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the issue is I need to have the form in horizontal direction in large screens and in vertical when shown in small screens. Your solution is just for vertical forms.

Comment: The clear buttons stay withing the input field regardless of the viewport changing if that's what you're saying. Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes but I noticed in your code the form is just vertical, demo is included. I am going to test it again.

Comment: The codes that you added made the form vertical all along. Please check out Demo1 link while changing the screen size.

Comment: I just included two screenshots to the question to clarify the issue.

Comment: Look at the updated one, its not exactly the same but it might help you accomplish what you want if you play with the CSS some more.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Submit</button>
      </span>
</div>
```

this should put the submit button inside input. let me know if it works for you

Comment: I suppose you did not get the question! I need to put the clear spans in their respective inputs not submit button.